# Backtracking algorithm to find out if the graph has a simple cycle with n vertices

Tags: python, algorithm, backtracking

I'm trying to create a backtracking algorithm which finds out if the given graph has a simple cycle with k amount of vertices. My current approach is this:

```
def simpleCycle(A, k, visited, currentNode):   # A = adjacency matrix, k = amount of vertices, visited = list of visited nodes


    visited.append(currentNode)

    if len(visited) == k and A[currentNode][visited[0]] == 1:
        return True

    for neighbor in range(len(A[currentNode])):
        if neighbor not in visited and A[currentNode][neighbor] == 1 and len(visited) < k:
            if simpleCycle(A, k, visited, neighbor):
                return True

    visited.pop()
    return False


A = [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
     [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
     [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]]

print(simpleCycle(A, 3, [], 0))
```

I've put it in python visualizer and I found out what the problem was. For my example I used this graph with the corresponding Adjacency matrix:

[image]

This code finds all the simple paths which start on the given starting node which is 1 in my example. The problem is that I don't know how to change the very first starting node, since I give it as an argument to the function. Now it finds the correct solution for k = 4 and k = 5. But for k = 3 it has to start at a different node than 1. Which the current algorithm can not do.

Now the question is: How do I change my code that after checking every solution for starting node 1, it also changes the starting node.

Pseudocode solution given:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Now that you have edited the question and added solution pseudo code, what is holding you back to implement that pseudo code? It seems you answered your own question by providing that solution in the question.

Comment: I was just pointing out that this was the given solution by school, which also isn't really efficient. However I came up with a different approach which I wanted to make work as well. Ofcourse I can implement the pseudocode but that's not what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I change my code that after checking every solution for starting node 1, it also changes the starting node.

That would not be an efficient solution. Instead you can keep the algorithm where you start at one particular node (assuming the graph is *connected*).

The trick is to mark each node that you visit with the distance you have travelled to it. Then when you encounter a node that you already visited on the way, you can look at the *difference* in distance. If that difference is `k`, you have a hit! We can use `visited` to both indicate the *fact* that a node was visited, and with which distance. If we start the distance counting from 1, then the value 0 can indicate the node has not yet been visited.

Code:

```
def simpleCycle(A, k):
    visited = [0] * len(A)
    
    def dfs(currentNode, depth):
        if visited[currentNode]:
            return visited[currentNode] == depth - k
        visited[currentNode] = depth
        for neighbor in range(len(A[currentNode])):
            if A[currentNode][neighbor]:  # edge
                if dfs(neighbor, depth + 1):
                    print("true", currentNode, "to", neighbor)
                    return True
        visited[currentNode] = 0
        return False

    return dfs(0, 1)

A = [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
     [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
     [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]]

print(simpleCycle(A, 3))
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems a bit more complicated than what we have to know for the class I'm following tho. I thought there would be a simple solution to what I've written. The efficiency doesn't need to be very good. For example I added the solution given by my school, which I think isn't very efficient either.

Comment: Sorry, but there is nothing more complex happening in this solution code than you already had. It uses a `visited` list, and your code also has a `visited` list. Your code uses the concept of distance by `len(visited)` and my code uses `visited[currentNode]` to have that distance... I don't see how this is complicated. I cannot bring myself to write code that is inefficient. Sorry.

Comment: Welp it might be because of the double functions that it looks more complicated. I'll try to implement this without the double functions

Comment: Oh, I see. You can make `dfs` a top-level function and pass `visited`  and `A` and `k` as extra parameters.